# Unable to reference two JSLINKs for my list view web part

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, list-view, jslink

I am working on an on-premises sharepoint 2013. and i have a list view web part inside my team site. now i have two JSLINKS which i want to reference inside the web part JSLINK section.

The first JSLINK will disable the title field inside the quick edit grid as follow:-

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.Name === 'LinkTitle';
        });
        if (statusField.length>0) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

While the second JSLINK will color code the rows:-

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
       function init() {
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
          Templates: {},
          OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
           var statusColors =  {
              'Closed' : '#FFF1AD',  
              'Resolved' : '#FFD800',
              'Active' : '#01DF3A' 
           };

           var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
           for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
           {
             //code goes here
           }
            ctx.skipNextAnimation = true;
          },
        });
      }
      RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/colorcode.js"), init);
      init();
    });
```

now if i reference each JSLINK separately inside the webpart>>JSLINK section i will get the desired results. but if i try to reference both JSLINKs inside the webpart>>JSLINK section as follow:-

```
~siteCollection/Style Library/colorcode.js;~siteCollection/Style Library/disabletitle.js
```

i will not get any results for the 2 JSLINKs .. so can anyone adivce how i can reference my above 2 jslinks inside the webpart??? again if i reference single JSLINKS i will get the desired results ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pipe between the two file paths:

```
~siteCollection/Style Library/colorcode.js|~siteCollection/Style Library/disabletitle.js
```